# C++ template specialization for N + 4 types?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I have a struct like

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    T value;

    void Set(const T& val) { value = val; }

    void Foo();
}
```

T can be int, float, char, short and long long or one of N other struct-based PODs.

There are about 50 or so PODs and they look something like:

```
struct POD1 { int i; char c; double d; }
struct POD2 { char c; double d; }
struct POD3 { POD1 p1; char s[10]; }
```

I'm wondering how to best structure this arrangement.  If I wanted the general T case to handle the PODs, would I necessarily need to provide explicit, concrete definitions of the int, float, char, short and long long cases?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say `the Set method doesn't make sense in the POD case`, do you mean that having the method doesn't make sense, or that the above given default implementation doesn't make sense? In the latter case, what should happen instead - calling some method on the POD struct?

Comment: Why do you say Set() makes no sense in the POD case? It would work as expected...

Comment: I mean yes it would work but in the case of the POD structs the end-user would prefer to have a Get() method to operate on the already instantiated type(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `Set()` is fine for any fundamental type, POD, or aggregate class type, as the latter class types will have a default assignment operator which Does What You Need.

The only question is how to call `Foo()`. Happily, we have type traits to deal with that, namely `std::is_fundamental`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct S
{
  T val;

  // Base case: call member `Foo()`.    
  template <typename U, bool Primitive, bool Array> struct callFoo
  {
    static void call(const U & u) { u.Foo(); }
  };

  // Specialization for primitive types (implement this yourself)
  template <typename U> struct callFoo<U, true, false>
  {
    static void call(U u) { /* fundamental implementation here */ }
  };

  // Specialization for arrays: call `Foo()` on every element.
  template <typename U> struct callFoo<U, false, true>
  {
    typedef typename std::remove_extent<U>::type V;

    template <std::size_t N>
    static void call(const V (&arr)[N])
    {
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
      {
        callFoo<V, std::is_fundamental<V>::value, std::is_array<V>::value>::call(arr[i]);
      }
    }
  };

  void Foo()
  {
    callFoo<T, std::is_fundamental<T>::value, std::is_array<T>::value>::call(val);
  }
};
```

(Some minor things: You might want to make `callFoo` private. And think about constness, too: if applicable, make `callFoo` and Foo` constant.)

Comment: Also why the different letter U?  Can it not share T?

Comment: @chriskirk: 1) Yes, arrays are also aggregates, thus copyable by default. I'd strongly recommend using `std::array` as a wrapper, though! 2) It's a different, unrelated template...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Even with C++11 this doesn't work: http://ideone.com/rbQWV.  `error: function template partial specialization 'callFoo<U, true>' is not allowed`  Also this fails if `T` is an array, but it works if `T` contains an array.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, of course, can't partially specialize functions. I changed it to a wrapper class. Thanks! Not sure about arrays, will test later. We may have to add another specialization for array types.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Hm, why do you create a temporary *instance* of a class only to call a static member function? Anyway, I added another test for arrays.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Because originally that was `operator()`.  You're right that instances aren't needed anymore.

Comment: Ah, there was another embarrassing mistake in the array implementation. Now it calls the helper again recursively, so that the array members may themselves be of any of the three types.